# LogstashでPostgreSQLに出力するときのエラー

Tags: postgresql

LogstashでPostgresqlに出力するときに次のようなエラーが出ます。

```
[ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread from class org.postgresql.Driver
```

出力を標準出力にすると動作するので、outputに問題があると思っています。
パイプラインファイルのoutputは次の通りです。

```
output {
  jdbc {
    driver_jar_path => "/usr/share/java/postgresql.jar"
    driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"
    statement => ["INSERT INTO test (result1, result2) VALUES (?, ?)",
      "test1", "test2"
    ]
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

何が間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

inputやfilterで同じDBのJDBCを使っているとエラーになるようでした